# Generating a static library and an executable with a single installation (autoconf)

Tags: c++, static, autoconf, automake

I know how to build a project or how to create a library using autoconf.

What I want to achive is to generate a static library and use this library to build a project in a single configure/make/make install run.

I want some source files to be put into library and the rest to be compiled using this library.

How do I modify makefile.am files and configure.ac to get it working?

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to do this is with libtool and automake "convenience libraries".
Here is a minimal example
for Makefile.am

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libExample.la 
libExample_la_SOURCES = lfile1.C 
bin_PROGRAMS = test
test_SOURCES = tfile1.C 
test_LDADD = libExample.la
```

for configure.ac

```
AC_INIT(test, 1.0)
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign])
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
AC_SUBST(LIBTOOL_DEPS)
AC_LTDL_DLLIB
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

This will build both a static and dynamic library libExample in the directory `.libs`.
If you want just a static library, you can pass `--disable-shared` to `configure`.

Comment: I'm getting this error when running automake:

src/Makefile.am:5: variable `libsadspider_la_SOURCES' is defined but no program or
src/Makefile.am:5: library has `libsadspider_la' as canonic name (possible typo)

Comment: It sounds like you don't habe libsadspider.la listed in lib_LTLIBRARIES, or it is misspelled.